# How many different ordered selections of $3$ balls are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

I have two hats. In one hat are balls numbered 1 through 15. In the other hat are balls numbered 16 through 25. I first choose a hat, then from that hat, I choose $3$ balls, without replacing the balls between selections. How many different ordered selections of $3$ balls are possible?

I made my solution and tell me if it's correct or not. But if any mistakes are to be found, I'd like to ask for clarifications. So, here's my solution:
$$2(15P3 + 9P3)$$
since there are two hats there's going to be $2$ ways. And for that, since there are two cases to choose either we could have the first hat from 1 through 15 or
16 through 25 where either we get $3$ from the 1st or 2nd - we then add it. Since without replacement, we could say that the number is to be reduce from succeeding stages(say 15,14,13 or in a manner of $15P3$, in the first hat and same technique with the second hat).

For the answer, I get $6468$ ordered selections.

Comment: The number of legal ordered triples doesn't depend on which hat you choose, so the factor of $2$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: Also, there are $10$ balls in the second hat, not $9$.

Comment: Which means that it gets double when it is not necessary,right?

Comment: Right. For example, the triple $(1,2,3)$ is legal, but there's no justification for counting it twice -- it's just one of the possible triples.